# Push notification for google calendar not working

Tags: php, google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I am using the php watch commant:

```
 try {
      $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($this->gapi->client);
      $channel =  new Google_Service_Calendar_Channel($this->gapi->client);
      $uuid = '27baf74c-59****************';
      $channel->setId($uuid);
      $channel->setType('web_hook');
      $channel->setToken($uuid);
      $channel->setAddress('https://*********.com/calendar_webhook');
      $watchEvent = $service->events->watch('primary',$channel);
      print_r($watchEvent);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print_r($e->getMessage());
    }
```

after that i get response like this for $watchEvent

```
Google_Service_Calendar_Channel Object
 (
   [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
    (
    )

     [address] => 
     [expiration] => 1471667969000
     [id] => 27baf74c-59d*****************
     [kind] => api#channel
     [params] => 
     [payload] => 
     [resourceId] => Ga-R5***************
     [resourceUri] =>        https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?key=AIzaS*********************&alt=json
     [token] => 27baf74c-5****************
     [type] => 
    [modelData:protected] => Array
    (
    )

  [processed:protected] => Array
    (
    )

 )
```

But in my notification url I don't get any message when changes in my calendar. Am I missing something!? In my response address parameter is empty. is there any issue. I have done all url verification in google. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must implement [`Watch`](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/push) method. To set up a notification channel for messages about changes to a particular resource, send a `POST` request to the `watch` method for the resource.

Each notification channel is associated both with a particular user and a particular resource. A watch request will not be successful unless the current user owns or has permission to access this resource.

Request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/apiName/apiVersion/resourcePath/watch
```

Start watching for changes to a collection of events on a given calendar:

```
POST https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/example.com/events/watch
Authorization: Bearer auth_token_for_current_user
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab", // Your channel ID.
  "type": "web_hook",
  "address": "https://example.com/notifications", // Your receiving URL.
  ...
  "token": "target=myApp-myCalendarChannelDest", // (Optional) Your channel token.
  "expiration": 1426325213000 // (Optional) Your requested channel expiration time.
  }
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "kind": "api#channel",
  "id": "01234567-89ab-cdef-0123456789ab"", // ID you specified for this channel.
  "resourceId": "o3hgv1538sdjfh", // ID of the watched resource.
  "resourceUri": "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/example.com/events", // Version-specific ID of the watched resource.
  "token": "target=myApp-myCalendarChannelDest", // Present only if one was provided.
  "expiration": 1426325213000, // Actual expiration time as Unix timestamp (in ms), if applicable.
}
```

After creating a new notification channel to watch a resource, the Google Calendar API sends a sync message to indicate that notifications are starting. The `X-Goog-Resource-State` HTTP header value for these messages is sync. Because of network timing issues, it is possible to receive the sync message even before you receive the `watch` method response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i got all this information

Comment: I found the issue due to my curl redirection used in my application. Now i fixed and i getting the hit from google into my application. Also we get the channel id as $_SERVER variable.

Comment: Thanks for responding mate!